# WordPress simple Image Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, image, shortcode

I am a newbie, please help me with creating a wordpress image shortcode, as simple as:

```
[img src=""]
```

Which shows its thumbnail (thumbnail width=100%), links to OR opens the same source image, when clicked.

I tried searching but could not find in existing plugins, please guide me if any.

Please guide me thoroughly for every copy paste in function.php or anywhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Add Shortcode
function img_shortcode($atts)
{
    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
        'src' => '',
        'link_to_img' => '',
        ], $atts, 'img'
    );

    $return = '';
    if ($atts['link_to_img'] == 'yes')
    {
        $return = '<a href="' . $atts['src'] . '">
                    <img src="' . $atts['src'] . '"/>
                </a>';
    }
    else{
        $return = '<img src="' . $atts['src'] . '"/>';
    }
    // Return HTML code
    return $return;
}

add_shortcode('img', 'img_shortcode');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

**USAGE**
*Without link:: In PHP*

```
echo do_shortcode('[img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/hello.jpg" link_to_img="no"]');
```

*Without link:: In Editor*

```
[img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/hello.jpg" link_to_img="no"]
```

*With link:: In PHP*

```
echo do_shortcode('[img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/hello.jpg" link_to_img="yes"]');
```

*With link:: In Editor*

```
[img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/hello.jpg" link_to_img="yes"]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to get image by ID instead src?

Answer (score 0):

The Gallery feature allows wordpress to add one or more image galleries to your posts and pages using a simple Shortcode

```
[gallery ids="729,732,731,720"]
```

[enter link description here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode)

Comment: I want a simple image, not a gallery, and not from same website but from an image url.